# Firebase database error

Tags: android, firebase, gridview, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app , in the activity i am receiving a list of data from firebase , if the data reference is empty then the app crashes , i tried to toast if Incoming List size is greater than -1 then it means no data is found so Toast a message that no results, but it doesn't work

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            view.setSelected(true);
            InComingDataList.clear();
            final String BG = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RequestsOrderByBlood").child(BG);
            Ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue(subRequest.class) != null) {
                        InComingDataList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(subRequest.class));
                        Collections.reverse(InComingDataList);
                        t.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        t22.setText("Showing BloodRequests for " + BG);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        RecView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                                int position = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                                listLength.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1) + " / " + adapter.getItemCount());
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(viewRequest.this, "Sorry No Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
                listLength.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    });
```

logcat

> ava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid
>   item position 1(offset:1).state:2
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5546)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5482)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5478)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2215)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1542)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1502)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1316)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollHorizontallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1049)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1723)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2927)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9998)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2828)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2499)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2816)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1848)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3046)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2777)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10233)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5397)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5233)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4834)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4700)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4891)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4700)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7359)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7237)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java

Comment: add more details about your code

Comment: final String BG = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RequestsOrderByBlood").child(BG);
                Ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

Comment: add it to your post, add the full class

Comment: this is gridview adapter to getting text from on click item grid

Comment: any help? please

Comment: add your logcat too, where it crashes ?